# If we were to discover an alien ecosystem that has a D-configuration of proteins, how would it react to our L-sided biology?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, environment, viruses

I'm working on a hard-sci-fi story where a scientist discovers microorganisms in our solar system with disastrous results. I was thinking about how any cross-contamination with an alien ecosystem would cause the organism to self-destruct in a similar manner to matter, anti-matter annihilation. I'm more inspired by science fiction works like War of the Worlds, The Andromeda Strain, Annihilation, etc., but I'm also interested in explaining how alien life could have evolved with novel-yet-similar mechanisms to life on Earth.

Leading me to the whole L-sided vs D-sided amino acids and protein synthesis. So how would the organisms interact with each other? I was thinking all the cells would self-destruct leaving behind traces of organic material and a myriad of novel viruses. Any material, references, or input is always appreciated.

Comment: I am a bit confused here, do you want your aliens to trigger Apoptosis in Earth cells, or are you asking if they could trigger it ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello @SupraGrumP.Heir, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. There's a few things that might help with this and future questions. (a) Stack Exchange is not intended to replace an education or to be a free research service. Ideally, it's a place where educated people who can't resolve a problem can approach their peers, whose combined experience can resolve the problem. (b) You're asking your question as if there's a Real World answer. [As you were told when you asked](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/112553) on [biology.se], this is a hypothetical question. In other words... (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... you're asking the wrong question. How L-sided and D-sided amino acid-based life would react with each other is *complete speculation.* That's actually our sweet spot... excapt that you're asking as if there's a Real World "right" answer. What you should be asking is, "When L-sided and D-sided amino acid-based life meets, I want X to happen, but I'm having trouble explaining it in a believable way. So far I have Y. What must I do to make Y believable?" (c) Thus, as written, your question is off-topic here, too, because all answers have equal value and that's prohibited. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... To understand these issues, please take the time to read our [tour] and the following two Help Center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. They'll help you understand the goals and limits of [worldbuilding.se], which will help you craft questions that will help you meet your goals. But, one last word of advice. (d) It's a fad right now to people to want to write "hard sci-fi" without first gaining the necessary education to do it. That's OK, we're happy to help, but there are very practical and very real limits to what "realistic" means. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... Please don't have an expectation that it's reasonable to make fiction factual. If you don't have the education to judge whether or not any answer we give you is "realistic," then you shouldn't be asking for that level of help. Our sweet spot is "believable." We're really good at it. But it means you need to set the expectations for the results so we can help you achieve them, rather than asking us to come up with the results, which often simply don't exist.

Comment: I was looking for input, I won't ask anymore questions in the future.

Comment: @SupraGrumP.Heir don't mind the comments, this is a pretty good first question

Answer (score 9):

When amino acids/azucars/attibic molecules are supplied in the "wrong" direction 3 things can
happen:

1. Let's take L and D-glucose as an example, in humans (and almost every organism for that
   matter) both L and D-glucose have a perceptible sweet taste but only D-glucose is
   efficiently usable, you see if we consume L-glucose simply nothing happens, it is not
   usable in the creps cycle nor in any anabolic metabolic pathway, even so there are
   isomerase that convert L-glucose into D-glucose that means that you can use some of the
   L-glucose but the production of enzymes spends energy and amino acids so it is very
   inefficient, this is an exception most of the sugars do not behave like glucose.
2. They do nothing, you see most receptors are stereospecific i.e. they only accept one
   configuration, for example methamphetamine has 2 configurations one is psychoactive
   the other is inert despite being chemically identical, simply many things in your chiral
   aliens would not be recognized by the enzymes and would just go in and out without any
   change, especially the amino acids which would not be recognized at all by the ribosomes.
3. They are toxic, remember what I said about most sugars not usually behaving as in
   example 1, well, what happens here is that your molecular if they can bind to enzymes,
   but this can not alter it so the enzyme is irreversibly blocked, so in the best case you lost a
   single enzyme perfectly functional and at worst you broke the entire molecular machinery
   of a mitochondrion, for example.
   The interaction of your bacteria will be moderated by these 3 possible reactions in different
   proportions, it is not impossible that you will kill all life on earth, but most likely the battery will
   die or nothing will happen at all.
   Finally, you never ask, but the only reason all life on earth is just an evolutionary whim and that is
   encoded in hyper conserved regions, nothing makes it impossible or even improbable that what
   you describe will happen, it is a 50 50 chance, but once an organism appears it will never change
   meaning.
   And no, a virus cannot infect a DNA counter-sense and most likely neither can a bacterium.

Comment: Good summary. I think you got your L's and D's reversed in your glucose example. L-aminos are the ones we use.

Comment: @RobertRapplean Not bad, L-amino acids are the ones we use, but it's not always the case with sugars, especially glucose. D-glucose is broken down into usable pyruvate in a process that involves converting it to L-glucose. However, L-glucose is not directly recognized for pyruvate synthesis

Answer (score 6):

Darth Momin provided a decent answer, but you don't need to go into that much detail.

Put simply, the organisms would be mildly toxic to each other in numerous ways, but it would prevent almost all infections from crossing over. Entities with inverse aminos wouldn't have an issue with normal interaction, or even touching. Sex might be a bad idea, and you wouldn't want to eat them.

D-amino acids block the pathways that L-amino acids would use, decreasing bioavailability. D-aminos are actually fairly common in our environment, but bacteria in our soil preferentially breaks it down to free up nitrogen, thus reducing our exposure to it.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3960212/

Comment: "Sex might be a bad idea" I think sex with aliens might range from awkward to dangerous even if their aminoacids were like ours.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw, I wish the rest of the world were so rational. Ever watch Galaxy Quest?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about the gender, you definitely don't want to eat them, but depending on their anatomy, sex could be a good idea after all. There couldn't be pregnancies or STDs.

Comment: @RobertRapplean I'll definetely have a look at that movie.

Comment: @darthmomin I agree about pregnancies. But as for STD's, only the viral ones would be at lower or zero risk of transmission. Bacterial and fungal ones might be just at the same risk.